# Prompt being ignored when executing remote shell script locally

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wget

I have shell script served somewhere on the net and I want to fetch it and execute locally. Normally I would do: `wget -qO- remote_script.sh | sh`

This works just fine, but when there's a prompt `read -p "Prompt" yn` in the script, it being ignored.

What is the simplest and shortest solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to avoid that shell's stdin being used for reading commands. Try this:

```
sh <(wget -q0- remote_script.sh)
```

The process substitution acts like a file so sh's stdin should still be available for that read command.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was thinking about, sh's stdin may be unavailable when piping in file's content. I've found another solution as well:
```sh -c "`wget -qO- remote_script.sh`"```
Which one is better?

Comment: @Roman With using `$()` instead of `\`\`` it might be better than `<()` since `""` completely allocates the whole script first on the buffer. With `<()` download might get delayed while the script doesn't read other lines of the script yet when pipe's buffer is limited. It depends on implementation though.

Comment: @Roman I actually suggest that this answer be accepted since the concept is similar and since you shared your own other answer to it as well. I gave my +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you're piping the contents of the script to `sh` which is line sending each command separately in a shell. If your script is:
    #!/bin/bash
    read -p "Prompt: " yn
    echo $yn

This is what is being executed:
    $ read -p "Prompt: " yn
    Prompt: echo $yn
    $

What you should do instead is save the script and then run it like this:
    $ wget -q -O myscript.sh remote_script.sh && sh myscript.sh